# what param need to pass to DAO method calling

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I just want to pass my entity object while calling controller method. How am I supposed to do this to insert the data into my database?

RegisterDAO.java

```
import com.samy.springmvc.beans.RegisterBean;

public interface RegisterDAO {
    void createUser(RegisterBean registerbean);
}
```

RegisterDAOImpl.java

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void createUser(RegisterBean regbean) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Register register= new Register();
    register.setId(regbean.getId());
    register.setUsername(regbean.getUser());
    register.setFirstname(regbean.getFirstname());
    register.setLastname(regbean.getLastname());
    register.setEmail(regbean.getEmail());
    register.setAddress(regbean.getAddress());
    register.setPhone(regbean.getPhonenumber());
    register.setPassword(regbean.getPassword());
    session.save(register);
}
```

registerationController.java

```
   @Autowired
    RegisterDAO registerDAO;

    @RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView returnSuccess()
        {
           registerDAO.createUser(new RegisterBean());
           return new ModelAndView("login");
        }
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me but the question is unclear, what is your requirment again?

Comment: I will make it clear I just want insert form data into database.but it's not persist the data whatever I provided in the form.

Comment: you are not setting form data into RegisterBean object

Comment: @Derick Daniel I did it ! right ? regbean.getUser() here getting the data and set it to register.setUsername() ? any problem in this !

Comment: @ram In the return success method, while calling createUser(), you are passing just a plain object, you need to set values and then pass

Comment: he's referring to the fact that you passed it a a 'new RegisterBean()' instead of getting data from the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the bean as a parameter to your controller.

1. If using form

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView returnSuccess(@ModelAttribute RegisterBean regBean)
   { 
     registerDAO.createUser(regBean);
     ...
   ```
2. If using JSON

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView returnSuccess(@RequestBody RegisterBean regBean)
   { 
      registerDAO.createUser(regBean);
      ...
   ```

Comment: in ModelAttribute need to bind entity class only right ! RegisterBean is not entity class it's just form bean class

Comment: @ram `Register` is your Entity - that's what you're saving to the database. `RegisterBean` seems to be your "DTO" (Data Transfer Object). You are doing the right thing translating the DTO into the Entity in your `createUser()` method. As long as your HTML form field names match the RegisterBean field names, you can transfer the values using the `@ModelAttribute`.

If you find my answer helpful please accept it.